# Div showing a activity indicator rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, progress

I'm uploading some text to my rails app. It is then processing it (adding tags, etc ...) and that takes a couple of seconds.

Ideally I'd like to have a "Processing div" similar to what is happens when you submit a query to Orbtiz.

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You might use flash notice. For example, on the start of process:

```
flash.now[:notice] = 'Processing div'
render :action => 'your action'
```

And then when your process is finished use this:

```
flash.now[:notice] = 'Successfully finished!!!'
render :action => 'your action'
```

But to have time animation you should write javascript code on the client side. I assumed that for the first time the simple flash notice will be enough for you.